# How to TestFor Player on certain block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a map where the player can only step on certain blocks, and if he/she steps off, they die.

How do I run a `testfor` where it tests for if the player is on the path, and if the player goes off of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! The command is:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ bedrock 0
```

Where bedrock is the block, and 0 is the damage counter.

After the "0" you can run any command you want! For example:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ stone 0 kill @a[c=1]
```

kill is the equivalent of the /kill @p command

So with this you can do whatever you want with your path!

Comment: You should **not** be mixing `@a` as the executor with `@p` as the nested selector. `@a` is the only selector that can target dead players, meaning `@p` cannot. The executor is killed on top of stone, but will continue being on top of that stone while dead. Since `@p` could not target them, it will instead target the nearest-living player, and continue to do so until every single player is dead and will not stop until that executor respawns. The fix is to use the same selector (`@a` with `@a[c=1]` or `@e[type=Player]` with `@p`).